# Converting SRTM to UTM makes pixels non-square

Tags: qgis, utm, srtm

I have a SRTM originally set to EPSG 4326. I need to convert it to UTM (EPSG 31983), in order to generate viewsheds.

The original version (EPSG 4326) has square pixels (0.000833333 x 0.000833333) but, when I convert to UTM, the pixel size becomes 91.9372 x -91.8611.

This means that, upon conversion, pixels are becoming rectangular. This makes it impossible to use viewshed in the processing toolbox.

Has anyone encountered this issue? What may be causing it? Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.2

Comment: This is the proper behavior. "Square" DTED cells aren't square -- They're spheroidal trapezoids (slightly shorter at the side closest to the pole). For most locations and most projections, projecting them shouldn't make them square.

Comment: Well, how to use viewshed, then? The algorithm demands UTM to be used and, simultaneously, pixels need to be square.

In past versions I never had this issue.